# Python to sum values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a Python code that reads the data from an excel file using `Pandas`.

**Code for your reference:-**

```
import pandas as pd

def myFunc():
   file = r"C:\Documents\myFile.xlsx"
   new_dataframe = pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet1')
   new_dataframe.fillna(value="No Data Found",inplace=True)
   print new_dataframe

myFunc
```

**Current Output:-**

```
             Name        date    amount_used
0             P1   2018-07-01          40.0
1             P1   2018-07-01          40.0
2             P1   2018-07-15          40.0
3             P2   2018-08-01          20.0
4             P2   2018-09-15          50.0
5             P2   2018-08-15          40.0
6             P3   2018-08-10          20.0
7             P3   2018-08-10          50.0
8             P3   2018-08-10          40.0
```

In the final output, I need to sum the `amount_used` column based on `Name` and `date` column.

**Expected Output:-**

```
             Name        date    amount_used
0             P1   2018-07-01          80.0
1             P1   2018-07-15          40.0
2             P2   2018-07-01          20.0
3             P2   2018-08-15          90.0
4             P3   2018-08-10         110.0
```

How can I achieve this using `pandas` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and then `sum`
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum

Comment: Welcome to our community :) You may want to elaborate your answer to make it a self-explanatory one.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [@Alex Z](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/76742/alex-z) solution, I was able to solve this question.

**Below is the reference code:-**

```
import pandas as pd

def myFunc():
   file = r"C:\Documents\myFile.xlsx"
   new_dataframe = pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet1')
   new_dataframe.fillna(value="No Data Found",inplace=True)
   new_dataframe.groupby(['Name','date'])['amount_used'].sum().reset_index()  #new line added.
   print new_dataframe

myFunc
```

**Output Generated:-**

```
            Name        date    amount_used
0             P1   2018-07-01          80.0
1             P1   2018-07-15          40.0
2             P2   2018-07-01          20.0
3             P2   2018-08-15          90.0
4             P3   2018-08-10         110.0
```

**Following is the reference link to the actual solution:-** [Link to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133583/10456127)

Hope this helps someone.